# How to use Grocer feedback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing a ruby on rails app and I want to send push notifications to iOS devices. I'm using gorcer gem, and I'm also interested in having some feedback but I cannot make it work. I'm following the git tutorial (https://github.com/grocer/grocer#feedback).

```
feedback = Grocer.feedback(
 certificate: "/path/to/cert.pem",       # required
 passphrase:  "",                        # optional
 gateway:     "feedback.push.apple.com", # optional; See note below.
 port:        2196,                      # optional
 retries:     3                          # optional
)

feedback.each do |attempt|
 puts "Device #{attempt.device_token} failed at #{attempt.timestamp}"
end
```

And the console always return nil.

I tried to disable push notifications and to unistall the ios app to check if there are any feedback but I don't receive anything.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In order for the feedback service to return anything, you must first send a push notification to a device that uninstalled your app (I'd try to send twice, just to be safe). Have you done so prior to testing this Grocer.feedback?

Comment: I'm having this same problem. feedback.count will return the right number of failed devices, but feedback.each does not run at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your code is correct and the .each loop does run in your example (if there is at least 1 failed push notification returned from the feedback service).

I think there is a bug in Grocer that only allows iteration on the feedback service a single time, and then after that the feedback object is set to nil. See this bug: https://github.com/grocer/grocer/issues/80

I think this explains why the code would actually work, but then not return anything in the console.

As a side note, it seems that the best way to test the APNs feedback service is to register a valid device token through a production or ad-hoc app. Then delete the app from your device and send another push notification to that token. The feedback service seems to register that as a failed attempt immediately (and repeatably).